# Location Biasing in google Places API for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I have bounds for four cities.

```
BANGALORE(12.784305f, 77.352505f, 13.178402f, 77.840023f, "GMT+0530", "IN"),
DELHI(28.370917f, 76.803156f, 28.882014f, 77.432123f, "GMT+0530", "IN"),
MUMBAI(18.863098f, 72.750398f, 19.295282f, 73.071748f, "GMT+0530", "IN"),
CHENNAI(12.822149f, 79.979980f, 13.324029f, 80.393727f, "GMT+0530", "IN");
```

I want to create location biasing using these bounds, so as when I search, result should be written from only these 4 cities.

I have created it for once city using the below code

```
let offset = 200.0 / 1000.0;
        let latMax = lat! + offset;
        let latMin = lat! - offset;
        let lngOffset = offset * cos(lat! * M_PI / 200.0);
        let lngMax = long! + lngOffset;
        let lngMin = long! - lngOffset;
        let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latMax, longitude: lngMax)
        let otherLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latMin, longitude: lngMin)
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: initialLocation, coordinate: otherLocation)

 **autocompleteController.autocompleteBounds = bounds**
```

So I want to know, how can we achieve this

Comment: You could calculate distances to each, see which is closest, and then use that city's location

Comment: hey @AMomchilov thanks, could you please elaborate.

Comment: are those cities in an enum?

Comment: Then what are they?

Comment: @AMomchilov, I had just typed them that way. So do you have any solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115435/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-ranjit).

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete controllers in the Google Places SDK for iOS only let you set a single rectangular lat-lng bounds to bias autocomplete results to.

If you really need a solution that displays predictions from 4 regions at the same time you could write your own UI which is backed by four [GMSAutocompleteFetcher](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_fetcher) instances, one for each city. When the user types text, submit it to all 4 fetchers and concatenate the results for display.

Comment: Hey @AndrewR thanks, but dont you think, the process will be slowed down ?